# What is the accuracy of the SQL Server 2008 Replication Merge:Conflicts/Sec performance counter?

Tags: sql-server, replication

We have SQL Server 2008 Merge Replication enabled, and I wanted to monitor any merge conflicts that arose.  I setup a SQL Server Agent Alert following the instructions [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/5293c1a5-4953-4428-acc1-f8c6a049cf76).  However, what I've found is that the Conflicts/Sec performance counter does not seem accurate at all.  *Every time* the Merge Agent runs (~every minute), the counter reports over 2,000 conflicts!  (I've verified this by running Performance Counter.)  This can't be correct.  Looking at the Replication Conflict Viewer we have **8** conflicts, and none in the last two hours.

So my question is, how accurate is this counter?  Is there another counter I should be using?

EDIT: Just to prove I'm not crazy, here's a recent image of Performance Monitor showing over 4,000 conflicts!

[image]

(click for larger image)

Comment: This problem was appearing on our development server, but never appeared on our production server, so I have to assume it was a bug/configuration problem/sunspot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the counter to monitor.  What are your conflict resolution settings set to?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I'm using the default resolver on all articles.

Comment: I'm also using row-level conflict detection on all articles.

Comment: Could someone be running large updates on two servers at about the same time?  The replication viewer should only be showing conflicts which need your attention, not all conflicts.  If the SQL Server is able to resolve them it self you shouldn't be able to see them (if I remember correctly).